# How to add a class to a List field based on the content?

Tags: views, entities

I have a List Field for the Articles that will work like a Category.

This is an image of the PSD file:

[image]
There are 6 options on the list so the user can select the appropriate one when creating the Article. The problem is that each of those options needs a different CSS class and it should still be possible to make a View for those contents and show them as shown on the next image.

The boxes with colors is what I need to create as the Category, but I cannot add CSS classes for each content on the list while having the View that shows those 4 articles.

Any idea how can I get this to work?

Answer (score 1):

Found the solution with the **Field Formatter CSS Class** module to get the css added, then for being able to use it on the Views module, the instructions from are (Drewpal's instructions):

'm using the views module. In order to pass the css property captured with the Field Formatter CSS Class module through to the Views module, you have to do the following:

> Go to ../admin/structure/views and edit the view that's displaying the field(s) where you want the css to be applied
>
> In the "Fields" section, add the content field that's capturing the css class (in my case it was Content: Style)
>
> On the configuration page, uncheck the "Exclude from Display" box and set "Formatter" to Key (if using Select List as in the video), then click apply
>
> Next, edit the field that you'll want the CSS class to be applied
>
> On the config page, in the "styles" section, check "Customize Field HTML" and then check "Create a CSS class"
>
> In the "CSS class" textbox enter the token from the field that holds the css class (note: the token should be the name of the field like this [feild_fieldname] - mine was [field_style])
>
> The select apply and it will pass the css class through.

More info here:
http://codekarate.com/daily-dose-of-drupal/drupal-7-field-formatter-css-class-module#comment-7154